# How to get blame information of a line of code on a repository from github API

Tags: git, github-api

I searched through all the existing github API s found in [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to get blame information of a certain line of code in a source file, but I couldn't find a way to achieve it, such API is not listed in the above site. Can anyone point me a way to get the blame information of a line of code of a source file, which is hosted in github repos without cloning it and running `git blame` locally.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

The GitHub API v4 has a working blame API. Here's an example of the proper query:

```
{
  # repository name/owner
  repository(name: "MidiPlayerJS", owner: "TimMensch") {
    # branch name
    ref(qualifiedName:"tim") {      
      target {
        # cast Target to a Commit
        ... on Commit {
          # full repo-relative path to blame file
          blame(path:"package.json") {
            ranges {
              commit {
                author {
                  name
                }
              }
              startingLine
              endingLine
              age
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works in the [explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) for me.

Comment: Can we add a specific range of Lines of Code in the above solution?

Comment: See https://developer.github.com/v4/object/commit/ -- the only parameter to blame() is path. You'll need to filter the results by the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There's no Blame API in the GitHub REST API http://developer.github.com/v3/

But you can fetch blame information through the new GraphQL API which is in early access mode. see this doc https://developer.github.com/early-access/graphql/

Comment: How do you create a query to get blame information using GraphQL?

Comment: As of this writing, I have not found any way to get blame information through the GraphQL API. If you look at the reference for Commit, it has a blame field, but there's no way to get a commit. I would guess that will be added as a connection through Ref, but I don't know what GitHub is planning there.

Comment: You can get to a commit reference (see https://gist.github.com/TimMensch/24c93785f1995542620bab94b92ab1ed ), but so far the blame API is throwing an internal error.

Comment: And I had a typo in mine. It does work. I'm adding another answer.